# Calculate max ‘win streak' over sequential documents on Mongo DB without using $accumulator and custom JS functions

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql-aggregation

Lets say I have a collection of documents like:

```
[
   { "createdAt": 1688383980100, "win": true },
   { "createdAt": 1688383980200, "win": false },
   { "createdAt": 1688383980300, "win": true },
   { "createdAt": 1688383980400, "win": true },
   { "createdAt": 1688383980500, "win": false }
]
```

How can I get the longest/max win streak?
I managed to get it via $group and $accumulator with custom JS functions.
But Digital Ocean does not allow JS on their Mongo DB instances.

So I spent almost a day trying many pipeline alternatives,
including many combinations of aggregators like $group, $project, $setWindowFields,
with $sum, $max, $cond, $multiply, etc.

Read a lot of articles, SO questions, searched the docs, talked a lot to chatGPT, no success.
Any tips or pointers are super welcome! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply `find().sort({ createdAt: -1 }).limit(1)`?

Comment: What do you mean by "the longest/max win streak"?

Comment: Your documents don't have `player_id` or `game_id` or anything else like that?   Just `created_at`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit a win streak is a sequence of game wins uninterrupted by any loss. In the example above the max win streak is 2 (two).

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti you can assume the list was already filtered by userId, so irrelevant here.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to group your entire collection (which is not recommended), you can use `setWindowFields`:

1. Use `setWindowFields` to mark documents which ends a win streak (so we can filter out all `win: false` documents)
2. `$match` to keep only "winning" documents, now that we have our mark
3. Format the documents
4. Add index to all "winning" documents
5. `$match` to keep only documents which ends a win streak, now that we have our index
6. Use `setWindowFields` to insert the index for the previous streak end
7. Format the document to calculate the win-streak size (since previous streak end index)
8. `$sort` and `$limit` the find the maximal value

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {createdAt: 1},
      output: {isStreakEnd: {
          $push: "$win",
          window: {documents: [0, 1]}
      }}
  }},
  {$match: {win: true}},
  {$project: {
      win: 1,
      isStreakEnd: {$cond: [
          {$eq: [{$size: "$isStreakEnd"}, 2]},
          {$not: {$last: "$isStreakEnd"}},
          true
      ]}
  }},
  {$setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {createdAt: 1},
      output: {index: {
          $sum: 1,
          window: {documents: ["unbounded", "current"]}
      }}
  }},
  {$match: {isStreakEnd: true}},
  {$setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {createdAt: 1},
      output: {streakSize: {
          $push: "$index",
          window: {documents: [-1, 0]}
      }}
  }},
  {$project: {
      streakSize: {$cond: [
          {$eq: [{$size: "$streakSize"}, 2]},
          {$subtract: [
              {$last: "$streakSize"},
              {$first: "$streakSize"}
          ]},
          {$first: "$streakSize"}
      ]}
  }},
  {$sort: {streakSize: -1}},
  {$limit: 1}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/feLuwDfXvgg)

This method allows to avoid grouping all documents into one large document (which has a size limit). It uses a pipeline that reduces the number of documents throughout the calculation.

If you can assume the maximal win streak is less than a reasonable number, (for example: 100), you can do it much simpler, using only one `$setWindowFields` step, by keeping the last 100 documents wins on each document...

Comment: Thanks Nimrod! The code works! I'll play with it and give further feedback later.

Comment: Outstanding answer but important to remember that the logic only works for when the incoming docs are filtered by `player` or similar.   If you want to find the player with the best winning streak out of >1 players, there are edge conditions where the wrong size of streak is calculated.  But again, this answer *will* find longest streaks over *time*.